# Dictionary Keys * values to a list in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

My dict is as follows:

```
the_dict = {'1': 2,
 '2': 4,
 '3': 3,
 '8': 3,
 '9': 3,
 '10': 4,
 '14': 4}
```

I need to multiply the keys by the values to create a long flat list.
My attempt is as follows but it screws up the 10 and 14:

```
new_target = []
for k, v in zip(the_dict.keys(), the_dict.values()):
    new_target += list(k*v)
```

This code produces:
`['1', '1', '2', '2', '2', '2', '3', '3', '3', '8', '8', '8', '9', '9', '9', '1', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '1', '4', '1', '4', '1', '4', '1', '4']`

That code comes close, but it doesn't work due to the following behavior on the 10 and 14; `list("10" *2)` produces `['1', '0', '1', '0']` instead of the desired `['10', '10']`.

How do I create the desired list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two changes you need to make to your code:

1. Why iterate through `zip(the_dict.keys(), the_dict.values())` when you can just iterate through `the_dict.items()` with the same results?
2. Notice that if you enclose the string within a list, it doesn't matter how long the string is:

```py
print(["10"]*2)
# Prints ['10', '10']
print(["1"]*2)
# Prints ['1', '1']
```

Also, as wim pointed out, the `list` function call is unnecessary as you are already creating a list.

With that said, below is the corrected code:

```py
the_dict = {'1': 2,
 '2': 4,
 '3': 3,
 '8': 3,
 '9': 3,
 '10': 4,
 '14': 4}


new_target = []
for k, v in the_dict.items():
    new_target += [k]*v
    
print(new_target)
# Prints ['14', '14', '14', '14', '10', '10', '10', '10', '2', '2', '2', '2', '1', '1', 
# '3', '3', '3', '9', '9', '9', '8', '8', '8']
```

Check out diggy's answer for a shorter list comprehension version!

Answer (score 6):

Adding onto M-Chen-3's answer, you can also condense it to something like this using [list comprehension](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/list-comprehension):

```
new_target = [k for k, v in the_dict.items() for _ in range(v)]
```